# PySpark : Cannot run program "/home/user/venv/bin/python": error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: python, pyspark

I'am trying to create a virtual env and start a PySpark-shell using it.
Here my code :

```
export PATH=/appl/python/3.6.6/bin:$PATH #location of python on the linux server
python3.6 -m venv ./venv1
source venv1/bin/activate
python -m pip install --index-url http://host/repository/pypi-all/simple --trusted-host host pandas
deactivate
```

(download packages from a local repository)

Now I start the PySpark-Shell with this :

```
pyspark --conf spark.pyspark.virtualenv.bin.path=/home/user/venv1 --conf spark.pyspark.python=/home/user/venv1/bin/python
```

It works but i can't run function that use sparkcontext or spark session. For exemple, i'am tryting to use sc.parallelize() or spark.createDataFrame() it bring me this error :

*java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/user/venv1/bin/python": error=2, No such file or directory*

Notice that i'am on a server on my entreprise, so i can only access to my folder in home.

May be the problem is /home/user/venv/bin/python is a symlink. So i retry with this command :

```
python3.6 -m venv --copies ./venv1
```

This replace the symlink by the real file or folder. But same error.

How is it possible that PySpark bring me this error while everything looks good, no ?

Comment: can you try running the following command `pyspark --conf spark.pyspark.virtualenv.bin.path=/home/user/venv1 --conf spark.pyspark.python=/home/user/venv1/bin/python spark.pyspark.driver.python=/home/user/venv1/bin/python`

Comment: You mean with --conf before last instruction i think. Same error :/

Comment: first check if you really have `/home/user/venv1/bin/python` . Maybe simply you don't have it in this place but in different place. Maybe you created `venv1` in different folder than `/home/user` so now you have `python` in different folder.

Comment: if it runs on other server then maybe it need path to `python` on this server, not to python on your local computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand why I have this error but I found a solution. My code works well with spark-sumbit but I want the PySpark-Shell.

My solution is to export these two variables :

```
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=./venv1/bin/python
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/path/python/3.6.6/bin/python3.6
```

and execute this line :

```
pyspark --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=./venv1/bin/python --master yarn --deploy-mode client --archives ./venv1.zip#VENV
```

It need that you have created a zip of your venv with :

```
zip -rq ../venv1.zip *
```